# Describe the universal covering of the graph $\Gamma$

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Could anyone help me with this problem ?, I am very confused.

Describe the universal covering of the graph $\Gamma$ with two vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$, and two edges $e_1$ and $e_2$, both of which start at $v_{1}$ and end at 
$v_{2}$.

Comment: Any reference which deals with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph is homeomorphic to $S^1$, so the universal cover is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

You can describe the graph structure of the universal cover by saying it is $\mathbb R$ with lifts of $v_1$ at the even integers and lifts of $v_2$ at the odd integers.  The intervening intervals are lifts of $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Hatcher's Algebraic Topology section 1.A is about covering spaces of graphs.

[image: Drawing of covering space]